# Bulk edit for large number of files not working?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, bulk

I'm on Sharepoint Online, and I have a document library of about 1600 files. I have about 1000 files that are Unassigned in a certain column that I want to change from Unassigned to some other category. I tried selecting all the files with Ctrl-A and using the bulk edit properties tool to change the Project column, and then I click Save, but the saving never finishes (I waited overnight for this, just in case), and when I check on the document library with a new tab, nothing seems to have actually changed. Is there a reason why bulk edit properties isn't working, and is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online, in the modern document library, I select bulk files and use the bulk edit properties to edit the properties of the files.

And it can work.

I suppose you select too many files to edit the properties.

I suggest you could select about 100 files to edit the properties of the bulk files.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the problem is not exactly too many files (although that does slow it down), but that I'm using Ctrl-A and selecting all the files to bulk edit, but the files aren't all loaded onto the page yet because I didn't scroll down all the way (like maybe 100 of the 1000 files will be loaded on the page), which seems to cause issues that prevent the bulk edit from saving

Comment: You could consider selecting the files manually.